Is this the correct way of using sessions with multiprocessing in a process safe way in Python?
I am going to implement requests with sessions in my application, but I have read some threads concerning issues with thread and process safety, but those arent exactlty recent.
My application run 800+ processes, so I am a little worried that data recovered from APIs get messed up.
I come about this model of implementation, so was wondering if this is a corret way of working with request sessions in a multiprocess program.
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

session = None

def initialize_session():
    global session
    if session is None:
        session = requests.Session()
        retry_strategy = Retry(
            total=3,
            status_forcelist=[429,500,502,503,504],
            allowed_methods=["POST"],
            backoff_factor=1
            )
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter( max_retries=retry_strategy, 
          pool_connections=1, pool_maxsize=1)
        session.mount("https://", adapter)


def worker(args):
  global session
  initialize_session()
  try:
    for i in range(10):
      print("I am process "+str(j)+" and my cookie is ")
      print(session.cookies.get_dict())
      session.cookies.set('worker', j)
      time.sleep(5) #do some api work, function calls, etc

  except:
    raise

processes = []
for j in range(0, 4):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(j,))
    processes.append(p)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()



The use of a session instance as per the OP is almost certainly not safe cross-platform. e.g., it won't work on MacOS. If your "API work" involves POSTing to some API then you might be better off using multithreading. Having said that, I'm not sure if requests.Session is thread-safe. If it isn't, you'll need to implement some kind of lock to protect it.
Here's an example of how you could do this with multithreading:
from threading import Thread, Lock
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from functools import cache

NTHREADS = 5
URL = "http://localhost:8000/post"


@cache
def getSession():
    session = requests.Session()
    retry_strategy = Retry(
        total=3,
        status_forcelist=[429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
        allowed_methods=["POST"],
        backoff_factor=1,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
    session.mount("http://", adapter)
    return session


def process(lock):
    with lock:
        response = getSession().post(URL, json={"FOO": "BAR"})
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json()["data"])



def main():
    lock = Lock()
    threads = []
    for _ in range(NTHREADS):
        thread = Thread(target=process, args=(lock,))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Hi, thanks for the answer. We are using processes instead of threads to avoid the GIL locks, so we really need the fastest response time possible. The app runs in Linux servers only. So if possible we would like to try to avoid other types of locks.
We are looking into sessions to ease the network/DNS traffic.
